# Edit Insufficient Privileges Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, security

Is there any way to gain access to the standard "Insufficient Privileges" page that everyone knows and loves(hates), in order to edit/replace it with something else?

I imagine something along the lines of creating a Visualforce page to render in its stead, but I'm not sure how to call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you definitely wouldn't be able to override it... The best you could do is write a function that checks permissions before executing whatever action, and then direct to your custom page. This would effectively "catch the exception" caused by lack of privilege (although its not actually an exception lol)