# How to override Insufficient Privileges Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, security

Is there any way to gain access to the standard **"Insufficient Privileges"** page and edit/replace it with custom error?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been asked and answered [here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12041/edit-insufficient-privileges-page) To quote the accepted answer from @RenegadeCoder:

> Well you definitely wouldn't be able to override it... The best you could do is write a function that checks permissions before executing whatever action, and then direct to your custom page. This would effectively "catch the exception" caused by lack of privilege (although its not actually an exception lol)

Thanks!